# Do flags get migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, flags

When questions are migrated to another site, do any flags on that question (and any of its answers) get migrated to the other site?

Comment: Like "belongs on Meta"?

Comment: Yup.  Those would be the ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From memory, no they don't. I say that because "we" regularly migrate posts from SO to MSO after they get flagged, and I don't recall having to clear any flags on MSO. It makes sense really - quite likely a migrated posts is flagged for migration, and it will soon get attention on the other site.

My ♦ only extends to SO and MSO, so it *might* be different in other scenarios, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Flags, open and close votes are not migrated.  The question, its up/down votes, the answers and their up/down votes, and the comments with their upvotes are copied.  Everything else is a clean slate.

It will get flagged quickly enough if there's a problem.